Sage Pastel SDK ImportDocument() crashing
I have a winforms application that integrates with Pastel Partner using the Pastel Partner SDK (Interop.PasSDK.dll).
When I try to import an invoice document (using SDK.ImportDocument(108, 6)), while Pastel Partner has the Process Customer function open, my application will go into a Not Responding state and eventually it will crash. Notice the 108 in SDK.ImportDocument(), it will import the document into a batch for later processing.
In other words, a user logs on to Pastel Partner, clicks on View -> Open Batches, selects the open batch, which opens up the Process Customer function, while this Process Customer function is open, I am unable to call SDK.ImportDocument() from my application.
The SDK does not return an error code, it simply causes my application to go into a Not Responding state and it will not continue execution, and eventually it will crash.
What might be causing the sdk.ImportDocument() function to crash after working the first few couple of times?
I've tried to monitor for memory leakages to see if some resources were not getting closed off properly but to no avail.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
